# JAX-WS webservice deployed in Tomcat(Tricky...)

Tags: tomcat, jax-ws

I saw lots of developers just blindly follow the step-by step instruction to copy JAX-WS RI jars to Tomcat endorsement folder. and didn't see anybody asked why.

1) If JDK 6 update 4+ has already include JAX-WS API & RI and 
2) Tomcat 6 is set up with JDK 6 udpate 4+ in the eclipse

Then why do we still have to copy those JAX-API jars to tomcat endorsement folder?

raise your hands if you don't know and just blindly follow the instruction :) or maybe I'm the one of few developers in the dark?

I have an assumption, I will accept your answer if it matches my assumption or your answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably to use an updated implementation. For reference, see this [s.o. question on the jdk jax-ws vs. metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625547/jdk6-when-to-use-bundled-jax-ws-implementation-versus-project-metro) and [this 2009 blog post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2009/04/tip_for_using_j.html) which talks about how to add endorsed jars to tomcat (i.e,. [create $TOMCAT_HOME/endorsed](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).) As of JDK 6u4, RI are bundled w/JDK; subsequent jdk updates have [included newer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825076/127971) implementations (RI): jdk6u31 has JAXB API=2.1/RI=2.1.10; JAXWS API=2.1/RI=2.1